# What is the best way to migrate to a new file share in a new domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, microsoft-office-2010

I am looking to move a file share (100 GB or so) from one domain/server to a new domain and server. I would like to do this with little to no downtime and if possible I would like to be able to map permissions from the groups/users in the current system to groups/users in the new domain.

A side question, a large number of the files in the system are office documents with hard links to the old file server. Any way to programmatically change all those links to the new file server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to be a bit of a mess. Are you migrating domains? If so you can use ADMT, which will move users, groups, and related permissions on migrated servers. If you're trying to map groups in `Domain` A with groups in `Domain B`, your best bet is to recursively snag the permissions in PowerShell, dump them to a file, and then feed them back into a script that will set them on the target server.

As for the hard links, I'm sure there's a way to do it programatically, but I'm unfamiliar with any supported way.

Comment: To keep the links functional, if you're actually retiring the old server, is to add its name to DNS as an alias to the new server, and allow alternate names via SMB  (setting in the registry somewhere.)

Comment: Currently we are migrating about 25 users off of a disparate file server that is on a separate domain all together. But we are carving the users out of a larger domain.

Comment: If you can use ADMT to migrate those users and associated groups into the new domain, you can then migrate that file server onto the new domain as well. ADMT will translate all ACLs appropriately. Then it's as simple as `robocopy /mir /sec /secfix` to copy everything in-tact to the new server.